# Restrict accessing toString using typescript interface/type

Tags: typescript

I want to have an interface like this:

```
export interface Point {
  readonly x: number;
  readonly y: number;
  readonly toString: never;
}
```

I thought it will work like this:

```
const p: Point = {x: 4, y: 5}; // OK
p.toString(); // triggers typescript error
```

However I get also this error on the first line:

```
TS2322: Type '{ x: number; y: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Point'.
Types of property 'toString' are incompatible.
Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

**Is there an option to restrict usage of toString on some interface, without the need to write type assertions like `const p: Point = {x: 4, y: 5} as Point;` everywhere?**

My use case: I am currently rewriting what used to be

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    toString() {
        return `${x} ${y}`;
    }
}
```

to interfaced object with companion functions:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
function pointToString({x, y}: Point) {
    return `${x} ${y}`;
}
```

and I want to make calls to `point.toString()` in old codebase trigger an error, because they currently do not since every object in JS has a `toString()` method.

Comment: Why do you want to make all of those calls error, given that everything in JS does indeed support `toString`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I explained it quite clearly with my use case, I want to restrict using Object.toString when the object acts under this interface since it is 100% a mistake.

Comment: *Why* is that a mistake, though? You haven't explained that at all - a `Point` *does* have a `toString` method, and if you want to override that the class was already a sensible way to do so.

Comment: old manner: const p = new Point(1, 1); return p.toString(); new manner: const p = {x: 1, y: 1}; return pointToString(x); . In new manner, calls to p.toString() are a mistake since they trigger Object prototype toString method with a different output, we should use pointToString instead, but I can miss many spots like that when refactoring old code.

If you are asking why I don't override toString - we are moving to functional approach with plain objects, we don't want to override toString method, we don't want to use that method at all, just to ensure we aren't calling it in legacy code.

Comment: Anyway, regardless of what my use case is and whether you consider it legit or not, I think it is still a valid question if it is possible to write interfaces in typescript that restrict access to builtin Object methods.

Comment: There are many places where it's called *implicitly*, though, e.g. in concatenation and template literals, so you may still have places the default implementation (`[object Object]`) gets used. And TypeScript's telling you the *right thing* - `{x: 4, y: 5}` *does* have props that `Point` excludes.

Comment: Well, OK, I won't probably cover template literals. But it will still help much to cover explicit usages at least. Anyway, Typescript is not 100% type safe, we always go with some tradeoffs.

Comment: "And TypeScript's telling you the right thing - {x: 4, y: 5} does have props that Point excludes." I know that. Thats how types work. A type / interface says what properties an object has, but doesn't say anything about other properties. So assigning {a:..., b:..., c:...} to interface {a, b} doesn't violate typings.

So although all objects in JS have particular methods, it is completely valid to have a type that don't expose them and let objects act under this type.

Comment: That's true in general, TS is structurally rather than nominally typed (although allowing extra properties isn't allowed for object literals anyway, see *"Object literal may only specify known properties"* - `const p: { x: number } = { x: 1, y: 2 }` also wouldn't work, although you can access that object just fine *via* that interface) and you've explicitly said it *must not* have a method that it *does*.

Comment: No, I did not say "must not have", I meant "will not be accessible". It is exactly the same as assigning `{a, b, c}` to interface `{a:..., b:...}` -  the actual object will have `c`, but will not be accessible under that interface. Unfortunately it seems typescript implicitly adds builtin object methods to all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the `unknown` type:

```js
type NullPrototype = Record<keyof Object, unknown>;

interface Point extends NullPrototype {
  readonly x: number;
  readonly y: number;
}

const p: Point = {x: 4, y: 5}; // OK
p.toString(); // TS error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

I called it `NullPrototype` because it's essentially the type-level version of this pattern in vanilla JS:

```js
const p = Object.create(null); // TS infers type `any`
p.x = 4;
p.y = 5;
p.toString(); // Fails at runtime, but passes type check???
```

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1108)'s a related issue on the TypeScript GitHub, though I don't think anyone's come up with this specific solution over there